# Synology NAS: going from 3856 bad sector count to 0

Tags: hard-drive, synology

I've received my monthly disk health report like this:

```
Dear user,

The following is your monthly report regarding the health of disks on
DiskStation. You can also check the health of individual disks at
Storage Manager > HDD/SSD > Health Info.


Disk 1:
        Disk Reconnection Count 2
        Bad Sector Count 3856
        Disk Re-identification Count 0

Disk 2:
        Disk Reconnection Count 0
        Bad Sector Count 0
        Disk Re-identification Count 0


Sincerely, Synology DiskStation
```

Since then I've made a task schedule every week.

Now I get:

```
Disk 1:
        Disk Reconnection Count 0
        Bad Sector Count 0
        Disk Re-identification Count 0

Disk 2:
        Disk Reconnection Count 0
        Bad Sector Count 0
        Disk Re-identification Count 0
```

How is that possible ?

Comment: My guess is its showing CurrentPendingSectorsCount rather than reallocatedSectorCount. When a bad sector is identified, it is not fixed immediately, but instead noted. the CurrentPendingSectorCount is incremented. Then next time a full disk check is performed (chkdsk or e2fsck or whatever) the blocks are actually reallocated to spare sectors on the disk, and their addresses remapped. at this point, the CurrentPendingSectorCount is de-incremented, and the ReallocatedSectorCount is incremented.  So, check the more detailed SMART stats in the Diskstation web console.

Comment: Also note, Pending and Reallocated sectors are a permanent phenomena. That you have that many is a very bad sign. consider the disk untrustworthy until replaced.